# Как "обрезать" ту часть изображения, которая является пустой?

Tags: html, img, css

Добрый день друзья! Я пишу сайт с нуля, сейчас закончил рисовать дизайн, но вот возникла проблема, взгляните на картинку

[image]

Красным пунктирным прямоугольником я выделил границы картинки с коленкой девушки, и всё дело в том, что границы картинки заползают на кнопку и потому в этом месте нажатие по кнопке невозможно будет сделать. Вопрос : можно ли как-то программно "обрезать" нижнюю часть картинки и по бокам, дабы пустое место на картинке не являлось его частью и можно было нажать на кнопку?

У меня уже был вариант - коленку девушки поместить на задний план, а кнопку на передний и обрезать часть картинки, которую занимает коленка у девушки. Но это на крайняк.

Comment: z-index в помощь

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/13968/soledar10 мне надо чтобы коленка девушки перекрывала часть кнопки.

Comment: если эта часть кнопки не кликабельна тогда может тег  map - определить координаты

Comment: используйте z-index и pointer-events: none; p.s. а на будущее (если судить по картинке, то более чем понятно какой тематики "сайт") - советую или переходить на нормальные проекты, или соблюдать осторожность при любой работе с подобными проектами (иначе крайне велик риск оказаться крайним в случае шухера).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вам ещё способ: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3RSR/1/

```css
.navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.girl {
  position: relative;
}
.girl img {
  display: block;
}
.gp {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 16;
}
#gp1 {
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 203px;
}
#gp2 {
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 204px;
}
#gp3 {
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 205px;
}
#gp4 {
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 208px;
}
#gp5 {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 214px;
}
#gp6 {
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 218px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="girl container">
  <img src="http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/13/1212/h_1386850247_6570738_be60b88f56.jpg" />
  <img src="http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/13/1212/h_1386850247_1561297_bd836a91c1.png" id="gp1" class="gp" />
  <img src="http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/13/1212/h_1386850247_1165173_33a8c4ac5d.png" id="gp2" class="gp" />
  <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/13/1212/h_1386850247_3634114_9c224a65a6.png" id="gp3" class="gp" />
  <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/13/1212/h_1386850248_4799952_fc751f47b6.png" id="gp4" class="gp" />
  <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/13/1212/h_1386850248_2899901_85e75be117.png" id="gp5" class="gp" />
  <img src="http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/13/1212/h_1386850248_7575389_0672aef103.png" id="gp6" class="gp" />
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="">пункт</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">пункт 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">пункт 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">пункт 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">пункт 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Он ужасен чуть более, чем полностью :)
Но задачу решает, притом никак не затрагивая саму менюшку.
Кликабельность кнопки при этом плавно обходит коленку.

А менюшку затрагивать не стоит, поскольку её вероятнее всего впоследствии будут редактировать люди, недостаточно компетентные в разработке сайтов, чтобы прописывать массивы значений для тэга . Да и даже самому разработчику не придётся этого делать, если пункты меню изменятся, и расположение кнопки по отношению к картинке изменится. Кроссбраузерность тоже имеет значение: ширина пунктов меню (а следовательно и положение данного пункта относительно картинки) может зависеть от шрифтов, которые как минимум в каждой ОС свои.

Порастягивайте вширь окно браузера: положение коленки относительно менюшки будет меняться, но работать корректно будет при любом положении.

Answer (score 7):

Вариант А: сделать на кнопке прозрачную область по форме коленки девушки и использовать z-index.
Вариант Б: скопировать часть коленки девушки на фон кнопки и использовать z-index.
Вариант В: использовать тег **<[map](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_map.asp)>**

Answer (score 5):

Вы конечно извините за такой вариант, но игры с z-индексами ни к чему не приведут. Я бы вырезал из макета конкретный сегмент с изображением колена и дал бы его как дополнительный backgroung для кнопки.
a { background: url(коленка.png) 20px top; }

Comment: игры с z-индексами могут привести к результату, причём почти к нужному. Единственным минусом этого результата будет не очень красивый код. @VenZell предложил это решение вариантом А. Кнопка просто делится на две части: одна, видимая, располагается под коленкой, а другая, невидимая, но кликабельная, выше.

С точки зрения задачи, как она поставлена, недостаток этого решения только такой, что часть коленки будет также кликабельной. Зато самый простой в реализации. А вот переносить часть коленки в кнопку — это как раз вариант плохой. Почему — видно из примера: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3RSR/1/

Answer (score 1):

Применить `pointer-events: none;` для изображения девушки.

Answer (score 0):

Отрежь колено  и оставь его на кнопке, т.е. часть колена станет кнопкой. Что бы убрать ссылку с коленки на кнопке воспользуйся тэгом map http://htmlbook.ru/html/map